# one-hot encoding and existing data

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

I have a numpy array (N,M) where some of the columns should be one-hot encoded. Please help to make a one-hot encoding using numpy and/or tensorflow.

Example:

```
[
[ 0.993, 0, 0.88 ]
[ 0.234, 1, 1.00 ]
[ 0.235, 2, 1.01 ]
.....
]
```

The 2nd column here ( with values 3 and 2 ) should be one hot-encoded, I know that there are only 3 distinct values ( 0, 1, 2 ).

The resulting array should look like:

```
[
[ 0.993, 0.88, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0.234, 1.00, 0, 1, 0 ]
[ 0.235, 1.01, 1, 0, 0 ]
.....
]
```

Like that I would be able to feed this array into the tensorflow.
Please notice that 2nd column was removed and it's one-hot version was appended in the end of each sub-array.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**Update**:

Here is what I have right now:
Well, not exactly...
1. I have more than 3 columns in the array...but I still want to do it only with 2nd..
2. First array is structured, ie it's shape is (N,)

Here is what I have:

```
def one_hot(value, max_value):
    value = int(value)
    a = np.zeros(max_value, 'uint8')
    if value != 0:
        a[value] = 1
    return a

# data is structured array with the shape of (N,)
# it has strings, ints, floats inside..
# was get by np.genfromtxt(dtype=None)

unique_values = dict()
unique_values['categorical1'] = 1
unique_values['categorical2'] = 2
for row in data:
   row[col] = unique_values[row[col]]

codes = np.zeros((data.shape[0], len(unique_values)))

idx = 0
for row in data:
   codes[idx] = one_hot(row[col], len(unique_values))  # could be optimised by not creating new array every time
   idx += 1

data = np.c_[data[:, [range(0, col), range(col + 1, 32)]], codes[data[:, col].astype(int)]]
```

Also trying to concatenate via:

```
print data.shape # shape (5000,)
print codes.shape # shape (5000,3)
data = np.concatenate((data, codes), axis=1)
```

Comment: Second col had values 0,1,2. I don't see how that created the stated one-hot encoded appended array. Typo maybe?

Comment: 0 is coded as 0, 0, 0.
1 is coded as 0, 1, 0.
2 is coded as 1, 0, 0

Comment: I don't need to have exact binary representation of the values.
I mean if 2 will be encoded as 0, 0, 1 and 1 will be encoded as 1, 0, 0 it's also fine for me, but I think that 0 should be encoded as 0, 0, 0.

Comment: What's `unique_values`, `col`?

Comment: col - the index of the column I want to change, ie delete and convert to one-hot by appending.
unique_values -- dictionary. Something like ['categorical_value_2'] = 2.
So length of this dictionary is number of maximum values for one_hot.

Comment: Could you add those in the code for Update. A complete verifiable working version of code with the minimal data to run it is always good to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
In [384]: a # input array
Out[384]: 
array([[ 0.993,  0.   ,  0.88 ],
       [ 0.234,  1.   ,  1.   ],
       [ 0.235,  2.   ,  1.01 ]])

In [385]: codes = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]) # define codes here

In [387]: codes
Out[387]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],   # encoding for 0
       [0, 1, 0],   # encoding for 1
       [1, 0, 0]])  # encoding for 2

# Slice out the second column and append one-hot encoded array
In [386]: np.c_[a[:,[0,2]], codes[a[:,1].astype(int)]]
Out[386]: 
array([[ 0.993,  0.88 ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
       [ 0.234,  1.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  0.   ],
       [ 0.235,  1.01 ,  1.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ]])
```

Comment: Lets say I have an array:
[
[ 0.993, 0, 0.88 ]
[ 0.234, 1, 1.00 ]
[ 0.235, 2, 1.01 ]
[ 0.234, 0, 2.01 ]
.....
]

Can you please include dynamic generation of codes array based on source array?

Comment: @user3489820 Should work regardless. Use that as the new `a` and would work without changing anything else.

Comment: Well, I believe it helped me to move further, but I am still stack..
1st: I have structured array, ie it's shape (N,)
2nd: I have much more than 3 columns...

Please check my post to see where I am right now.
I will mark a question as answered, but will be grateful if you help me to advance even further.